# Test IMAP connection to Outlook using OpenSSL

Tags: outlook, openssl, imap

I am trying to access the Outlook mail server via IMAP using PHP. As this is not working as intended and the error messages are not helping, I looked up ways to test the basic connectivity and came across the following line of code:

`openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993`

This should, supposedly, let me connect to the mail server using an encrypted connection, so that I can then issue some commands to actually log in etc.

However, the command only generates the following output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 313 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I have tried researching the error message (`write:errno=104`), which lead to some suggestions like enforcing TLSv1.2 using the `-tls1_2` parameter, neither of which made any difference.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I already ran this command on Ubuntu and Windows 10 using the latest version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Works for me: `* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TABPADQAUAAxADIAMwBDAEEAMAA0ADcAMAAuAEcAQgBSAFAAMQAyADMALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]`. Maybe you're behind a proxy server? You could also try: `openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:143 -starttls imap`

Comment: @Wodin The latter works more or less, at least it says `CONNECTED(00000003)` and gives me the opportunity to input stuff, none of which causes any reaction though. However you are correct, I am in an enterprise network behind a proxy server. What are the consequences of this setup?

Comment: `openssl s_client` makes direct connections by default. Recent versions have a `-proxy` option, but I don't think there's a way to specify a username and password and anyway it doesn't look like it would support an MS proxy. You could try connecting via http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You could also see if `curl` works better for you: https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/reademail or https://gist.github.com/akpoff/53ac391037ae2f2d376214eac4a23634 . Also try adding `-crlf` onto your `openssl s_client` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can connect using your command, but I needed to force `\r\n` line ending characters using the `-crlf` option when connecting in order to be able to type commands and have the server recognise them.

You can also add `-quiet` to reduce the amount of output:

```
openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993 -crlf -quiet
```

However, it seems the connection is getting reset in your case. This means there's some sort of network issue. There might be a firewall blocking your access to port `993` on `outlook.office365.com`. e.g. this might be the case if you normally have to connect via a proxy server.

Recent versions of `openssl s_client` have a `-proxy` option, but don't seem to allow specifying a proxy username and password. Also it might not work with your proxy even if you don't need to authenticate to the proxy server. One workaround might be to use http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/. I have tried it in the past, but it was over 15 years ago.

You could also try using `cURL`'s IMAP support instead of `openssl s_client`, since it has better proxy support.

Another possibility is to connect to port `143` and use `STARTTLS` instead of connecting to port `993`. Obviously if port `993` is firewalled then port `143` might also be, but in your case it seems like it is allowed:

```
openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:143 -starttls imap -crlf -quiet
```

Comment: Adding `-proxy` with our proxy IP and port actually solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy and can't connect to the IMAP server directly, then you can also use something like [EmailEngine](https://emailengine.app/) that handles connections itself and allows access mailbox contents via a REST API.

Answer (score 0):

We saw this error because `outlook.office365.com` was resolving to an ipv6 address on the server. We had to update our firewall rules to include the ipv6 addresses of our servers to allow this traffic, and it started working properly.